# Restoring Azure backup in Local machine

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I need to take a backup of my database on Azure and I need to recover that backup into my local machine. Since SQL and Azure SQL are different, would I be able to backup the Azure SQL through the PowerShell commands and use it to recreate the database on a non-Azure SQL server without too much trouble?

Could some one help me on this?

Answer (score 6):

This is possible. One option is the following:

1) Export your database to Azure Storage with the [export PowerShell cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546720.aspx) or using the [Azure Portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh335292.aspx).

2) Open up SQL Sever Management Studios and connect to your local SQL server.

3) Right click on "Databases" under your non-Azure SQL server.

4) Click Import Data-tier Application.

5) Connect to your Azure Storage Account.

6) Provide your storage account key and storage account name. This can be found by logging into https://manage.windowsazure.com/ then go to Azure Storage and click "manage access keys".

7) Select your storage container and then your .BACPAC file to import.

8) Run the import to create the database on your local SQL server.

You can learn more about migration with [Data-tier Application backup packages here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use existing tools rather than writing your own script to do this.

1. If it is a one time job or a multiple times manual job then use SQL Azure Migration Wizard from - 
   https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/
2. Or if it a daily sync kind of stuff, then you can simply rely on Azure Data Sync service to have a local  or on-premise copy of DB that is in sync with latest SQL Azure on cloud.